# Fourier transform of a product

Tags: fourier-transform

I have: $$g_\epsilon(x)=\sin(x)e^{-\epsilon|x|}$$ of which I want to compute the $F$-transform. Now, I know that singularly the two components of the product function have their own transforms: $$\hat{\sin(x)}=i\pi[\delta(\xi-1)-\delta(\xi+1)]$$ $$\hat e^{-\epsilon|x|}={2\epsilon \over \epsilon^2+\xi^2}$$

The question is, do I really have to manually go through the whole $$\int_Rg_\epsilon(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx$$

or can I use the individual transforms in a smarter way to make it easier for myself?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Use the convolution theorem.

Comment: You surely mean $\widehat{\sin(x)} = i \pi [ \delta \ldots$, where $\hat{}$ denotes the fourier transform (and the same in the line below), right?

Comment: I did mean that, I'm sorry. I've edited the post to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the duality property, the Fourier transform of $x(t)y(t)$ is ${1\over 2\pi}X(j\xi)*Y(j\xi)$ where $*$ denotes the convolution. Since $$\sin x\iff {\pi\over j} [\delta(\xi-1)-\delta(\xi+1)]\\e^{-\epsilon |x|}\iff {2\epsilon\over \xi^2+\epsilon^2}$$we obtain $$e^{-\epsilon |x|}\sin x\iff {\epsilon\over j} \left[{1\over (\xi-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2}-{1\over (\xi+\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2}\right]$$

Comment: Can't believe I forgot I could use the convolution theorem this way. For some reason I only remembered it the other way around (transform of convolution = product of transforms). Thank you very much to the both of you!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!!